# how can I access the variables of a service in the template of a component in angular

Tags: angular, service, components

I have a service where I make a request to an api and I get the data. then in the .ts file, I store that data in a service variable. now the problem arises when I try to access that service variable in the .html of that component xq that variable is not defined in the .ts, that is, it is not the component but the service. How could I access this service variable from several components?

este es el codigo de mi servicio:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HostlistService {
  inmuebles: Inmueble[] = [];
  cabecera = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': ""
  }

  parametros = {
    'grant_type':'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 3,
    'client_secret': ''
  }


constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

}


obtenerToken(){
  return this.http.post<any>('https:',this.parametros);
}


obtenerInmuebles(resultToken){
  this.cabecera.Authorization=resultToken.token_type+" "+resultToken.access_token;
  console.log("----->"+this.cabecera.Authorization);
  return this.http.get<any>('',{ headers: new HttpHeaders(this.cabecera) });
}


}
```

This is the code of the component where you called that service and saved the data in a service variable:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HostlistService } from '../servicios/hostlist.service';

import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})

export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  z: number=0;

  url: string = "URL";

  constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.hostlistService.obtenerToken()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(resultToken => {
          //do whatever you want to do with the token
          //i.e. Save the token in the localstorage like this -
          localStorage.setItem("token",resultToken.access_token);
          return this.hostlistService.obtenerInmuebles(resultToken);
        })
      )
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            this.cargarJson(result);
          },error =>{
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
    }

    /*this.hostlistService.getInmuebles().subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log("-----------_>"+result.data);
      },error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );*/

  /*
  anteriorInmueble(){
    (this.i<=0) ? this.i=680: this.i=this.i-5;
    console.log("AntIn VALOR DE I: "+this.i);


  siguienteInmueble(){
    (this.i>=680) ? this.i=0: this.i=this.i+5;
    console.log("SigIn VALOR DE I: "+this.i);
  }*/


// metodo para cargar el Json recibido de la petición
  cargarJson(result){
    var foto1,foto2: string;
    foto1 = "fot0", foto2 = "fot";
    var precio: number=0;
    var i,j: number=1;

                for(const item of result.data) {
                    var pos: number=0;          //variable que define la posicion a almacenar en el vector
                    pos =0;
                    console.log("POS----->"+pos);
                    var inmueble = new Inmueble();
                    inmueble.fotos = [];
                    inmueble.nombre = item.nomb_prod_c;
                    inmueble.id = item.id_c;
                    inmueble.estacionamiento = item.estan_c;
                    inmueble.baño = item.banof_c;
                    precio = item.price;
                    precio = Math.round(precio*100)/100;
                    inmueble.precio = precio;
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot01_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot02_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot03_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot04_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot05_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot06_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot07_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot08_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot09_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot10_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot11_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot12_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot13_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot14_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot15_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot01_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot16_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot02_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot17_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot03_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot18_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot04_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot19_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      (item.fot05_c != "") ? (inmueble.fotos[pos]="fot20_c", pos++): (inmueble.fotos[pos]="");
                      if(pos == 0){
                        inmueble.fotos[pos]="n";
                      }
                    this.hostlistService.inmuebles.push(inmueble);  //se almacena el inmueble en el vector de inmuebles


            }
            //console.log("************:"+this.inmuebles[1].fotos[0]);


    }

    anteriorInmueble(){
      (this.z<=0)? this.z=680: this.z=this.z-1;
    }


    siguienteInmueble(){
      (this.z>=680)? this.z=0: this.z=this.z+1;
    }



  consultarPais(){

  }
}
```

I want to be able to access the service array in the multi-component .html template. How could I do it? I have read that with observables and using BehaviorSubject but I understand absolutely nothing of observables for more than I have read, I do not know how to do. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want. Are you wanting to access the `inmuebles` array from the service from the template? If that's all you're trying to do, it should be achievable by just changing `constructor(private hostlistService: HostlistService)` to `constructor(public hostlistService: HostlistService)`. If the service is not public, it's not accessible in the template.

Comment: Hello @Jacquesジャック Thank you for responding. what I want is to be able to access the values of the service array in the .html template, do something like this:<img src="{{url}}{{hostlistservice.inmuebles[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">

Comment: Then what I commented should work. Someone else already answered the same thing with an example. Good luck.

Comment: I think if it works, the problem is that it is not showing me the data, I think it's because I try to show them before I finish filling the array and that's why it does not show me anything, but I do not know how to do it, I put this condition: <div * ngIf = "this.hostlistService.inmuebles && this.hostlistService.inmuebles.length; else wait"> and if it enters the conditional but the data prints them blank.

Answer (score 1):

Make your service public,as `constructor(public hostlistService: HostlistService)` then inside the template you can do something like,

```
<div *ngFor="let data of this.hostlistService.inmuebles">
  <span>{{data}}</span>
</div>
```

In short inside template use `this.hostlistService.inmuebles` to access it.

Comment: I think if it works, the problem is that it is not showing me the data, I think it's because I try to show them before I finish filling the array and that's why it does not show me anything, but I do not know how to do it, I put this condition: <div * ngIf = "this.hostlistService.inmuebles && this.hostlistService.inmuebles.length; else wait"> and if it enters the conditional but the data prints them blank.

Comment: Yes your approach is right. Create a flag and do `*ngIf="flag"` at the outermost div. Now when you have done all the fetching of data from API and created the array., then only make the flag false. This time view renders, it will show the data as well.

Comment: But still does not show me the data, put a flag in the .ts after clicking it for that it is placed in true, and then in the .html I verify if it is in real beginning to show the data but it does not show anything. What could be a friend?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz of what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do not need to include “this.” in the template, just “ hostlistService.inmuebles” is enough.